# Detached ViewController Error

Tags: ios, swift

While presenting a view controller XCode warns me :
`Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged`

Why it is happening?

Comment: From where you are presenting viewcontroller ? this warning can comes in many different situations. share necessary code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens when you present a UIViewcontroller on `viewDidLoad()` because till then the view is not loaded and you are presenting a new UIViewcontroller there.

Try to present another view/UIviewcontroller after viewDidAppear() or inside if required.
or just to remove warning you can use:

```
self.view.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController("vc to present", animated: true, completion: nil)
```